# Complex Solution of a Transcedental Equation

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

How to find the complex solution to equation $e^x-x=0$ or $x-\log(x)=0$ by numerical methods ? What are the best methods to solve such transcendental equations with complex solutions?

Comment: [Numerical root finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Iterative_methods)?

Comment: We can find root in real domain of such equations by using an initial approximated guess obtained by observing sign changes of function through trial and error way and then using Newton's or other Methods. But I am clueless about obtaining roots of transcendental equations  in complex domain. If any good work is done on such topic please give me references.

Answer (score 2):

Provided, as usual, a reasonable starting point $x_0$, Newton method works perfectly well in the complex domain.

For example, looking for the zero of $$f(x)=e^x-ix$$ and using $x_0=0$, the successive iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -0.5000000000-0.5000000000\, i \\
 2 & -0.3702877642-0.5784979316\, i \\
 3 & -0.3746937523-0.5764142810\, i \\
 4 & -0.3746990207-0.5764127230\, i 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I feel f(x) here should be f(x)=e^(x)-x but not f(x)=e^(x)-ix ? Why imaginary 'i' is introduced here ?

Comment: @PrasenjitDWakode. It was just to make a problem with a complex solution.

Comment: yeah got it ... i think for case of my example, a starting guess should be an imaginary number in order to get imaginary root. i'll work on it. Thanx.

Comment: i checked, if we write x-log(x)=0 , then for any complex or real number as starting guess, we get the root which is complex in this case.

Comment: @PrasenjitDWakode. You made it ! Great !

Comment: I tried finding roots of x=logx , x=loglogx , x=logloglogx , x=logloglogloglog .....

Comment: I tried finding roots of x=logx , x=loglogx , x=logloglogx ,  x=loglogloglogloglog .....x etc. which contains any finite number of log functions and found that all of these equations have same root as x=0.3181315052048…+i1.3372357014307..... . I cant understand why all such equations have only this one unique root ? More elaboration on it will be welcomed.